# How to configure controller to return null instead of Guid.Empty?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

To make developers of frontend for my ASP.Net Core 2.2 API life easier, I would like them to receive "null" instead of Guid.Empty value (defined in .net core as "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000").

It's not complicated to achieve this behaviour by creating dtos like this:

```
public class ExampleDto
{
    public Guid? Id { get; set; }
}
```

and then mapping them like this

```
public static void MapExampleEntity(this AutoMapperProfile profile)
{
    profile.CreateMap<ExampleEntity, ExampleDto>()
    .ForMember(dto => dto.Id, o => o.MapFrom(e => e.Id == Guid.Empty ? null : e.Id);
}
```

however, that's a lot of code duplication for task I feel controllers should be able to handle with some configuration. Is it possible to achieve this behaviour by default?

*Edit to further specify my problem* (I received several working solutions, but I don't feel like any of them is 100% clean way to achieve what I want to do):

I know that the general movement is to leave null and that is also the reason why I don't want to pollute my code with nulls. I would like to keep my dtos in this form:

```
public class ExampleDto
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

instead of this form:

```
public class ExampleDto
{
    public Guid? Id { get; set; }
}
```

to avoid infinite HasValue() checks. Hovewer, I think that it is far more informative and consistent to return this (see customerId):

```
{
"Id": "b3431f4d-ef87-4fb5-83e0-995a9e7c9f6a",
"Name": "A001",
"Description": null,
"Currency": null,
"CustomerId": null,
"Customer": null,
"CountryIso": 2
}
```

than this:

```
{
"Id": "b3431f4d-ef87-4fb5-83e0-995a9e7c9f6a",
"Name": "A001",
"Description": null,
"Currency": null,
"CustomerId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
"Customer": null,
"CountryIso": 2
}
```

which is current behaviour. Those are the reasons I would like to let the Guid.Empty => null mapping do the controller instead of AutoMapper (if this behaviour is possible).

Comment: I don't see any duplication. Where is the duplication? Can you show some more code to show the duplication?

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, the duplication lies in the fact that I would need to configure EVERY dto using Guid this way (and that's a lot of dtos)

Comment: Generally, the move is away from returning null objects (see C# 8 for example). This is with good reason - how many times does the question "what is this null reference exception" come up on this board?

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Custom-type-converters.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, no idea why I didn't found this solution before asking here, but I feel like it would be appropriate to write it here (since I already asked the question) for future developers that might face the same problem.

**It is indeed possible to format controller output without manually checking value in every Dto or add AutoMapper line to it's mapping configuration!**

First create class derived from JsonConverted like this:

```
   public class NullGuidJsonConverter : JsonConverter<Guid>
   {
      public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, Guid value, JsonSerializer serializer)
      {
         writer.WriteValue(value == Guid.Empty ? null : value.ToString());
      }

      public override Guid ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Guid existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
      {
         var value = reader.Value.ToString();
         return reader.Value == null ? Guid.Empty : Guid.Parse(value);
      }
   }
```

and then add this class to Mvc settings in Startup.cs

```
services.AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(options =>
            options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Insert(0, new NullGuidJsonConverter()))
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

And that's it! Controller is now handling conversion from Guid.Empty value to null!

Comment: Actually an AM type converter that does the same is even simpler :)

Answer (score 0):

Guid is a value type as you already know. If you want to send null instead of Empty Guid, you could check if ActualCustomerId == Guid.IsEmpty and if true, CustomerId = null. Otherwise as you said, Nullable type is a way to go. Apologies if this is not what you want. This means you will need to check if Guid is empty, then set null to CustomerId if empty.

Comment: Yep, I am aware of this solution, but I don't want to do check manually every time. Sounds like something you don't want to have in codebase with a lot of dtos :(

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
public class ExampleDto
{
    public Guid? Id { get{ return Id == Guid.Empty ? null : Id; } set; }
}
```

Comment: This is indeed working solution, however, it just moves code duplicating from AutoMapper to DtoClasses (would need to specify Guid getter in every Dto)